# Lifetime extension of temporary objects: what is the full expression containing a function call?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, lifetime

## Introduction

Say there is a `Container` class which stores `Widget` objects.
There is an iterator class in charge of navigating such container. This iterator class (`MyIterator`) takes a const-reference to a vector of `Stuff` in its constructor, which it needs to iterate over the right elements in the container. The code may look like this:

```
class MyIterator
{
public:
    MyIterator(
        const Container& container,    // Container to be navigated
        const std::vector<Stuff>& vec) // Parameter which controls the behaviour of the iteration
    : container(container)
    , stuffVector(vec)
    {}
    
    ...

private:
    const Container& container;
    const std::vector<Stuff>& stuffVector;
};
```

## The problem

I'm curious about the binding of *rvalue*s to const references, and how the lifetime extensions work.

While `vec` can be bound to a temporary *rvalue*, that will cause `stuffVector` to be a dangling reference once the *rvalue*'s lifetime is over. So code like this, aimed to create an iterator for object `myContainer` is wrong:

```
MyIterator it = {myContainer, {stuff1, stuff2, stuff3}};
// Here it.stuffVector is a dangling reference!
```

Reading up on lifetime extension of temporary objects in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) I found:

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary object or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary object is extended to match the lifetime of the reference (...)
> There are following exceptions to this lifetime rule: (...)
>
> - a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists **until the end of the full expression containing that function call**: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference.

## The question

The highlighted part leads me to this question: would this piece of code succeed in getting a filtered version of the contents of `myContainer`?

```
std::vector<Widget> filteredWidgets;
std::copy_if (
    MyIterator{myContainer, {stuff1, stuff2, stuff3}},
    MyContainer.end(),
    std::back_inserter(filteredWidgets),
    [&](Widget w) { return ...; });
```

The second argument is an *rvalue*, so there is the danger of creating a dangling reference, but my understanding of the documentation is that the *rvalue*'s lifetime will be extended untill the end of `std::copy_if`, so it would be fine. Which one is it?

**NOTE:** I am aware the problem and the design, as stated, might seem a bit strange, but it's inspired in real code I've found in the wild. I'm interested in the limits of the lifetime extension, not so much in coming up with different designs which would make the question irrelevant.

Comment: @273K The argument `{stuff1, stuff2, stuff3}` for the `const std::vector<Stuff>&` parameter of the constructor will cause creation of a temporary `std::vector<Stuff>` with that as initializer and to which the reference in the parameter will be bound.

Comment: Even if the solution works, it makes `MyIterator` a very brittle class. A future developer would have no indication that the solution *requires* that the `MyIterator` must be part of the function call expression. It is normally assumed that the behavior should be the same if the `MyIterator` initialization occurred outside of the function call. Someone might try to change the code for clarity, or try to use `MyIterator` somewhere else and accidentally break the code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the input. I agree it's not great to have code which breaks by simple re-arranging. I was mostly curious about whether the code as it stands was broken or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the whole `std::copy_if` call is the *full-expression* and the temporary `std::vector<Stuff>` will be destroyed only after the call returns.

This is different from by-value function parameters. If the constructor took a `std::vector<Stuff>` instead of a `const std::vector<Stuff>&`, then it would be implementation-defined whether the object lives that long or is destroyed immediately when the constructor returns.

---

A full-expression is one of the expressions listed in [[intro.execution]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.execution#5). None of the specific cases (such as unevaluated operands, immediate invocations, etc.) apply here and so falling through, the relevant condition is:

> an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression and that is not otherwise part of a full-expression.

The `copy_if` call expression is the only one in that statement to which this applies (outside of the lambda body).